# Inlinely Inline Enumerate

Tags: enumerate

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{indentfirst,mathpazo,multicol,enumerate,booktabs,mathcmd,cancel,array,tabularx,fancybox,ascmac,bigstrut,etoolbox,stmaryrd,xspace,skak,ragged2e,pmboxdraw,bbding,array,fontspec,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,mathtools,tikz,graphicx,fancyhdr,geometry,tabulary}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \begin{enumerate*}
\item$ 4+6\sqrt{2} $\item$ -3 $\item $ 2\sqrt{2} $\item $ 2\sqrt{2}+2\sqrt{5}-2\sqrt{3} $\item $ -2\sqrt{2}-3\sqrt{3} $\item $ -30\sqrt{2} $\item $ 6\sqrt{6} $\item $ 60a $\item $ -36 $\item $ 75 $\item $ 45 $\item $ \frac{3\sqrt{a}}{a^2} $\item $ x^2\sqrt{7x} $\item $ x\times\frac{\sqrt{y}}{y} $\item $ 5z\sqrt{5z} $\item $ 5t\sqrt[3]{2t} $

\end{enumerate*}    
\item $x=y$
\item$y=z$

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

I am trying to make item 1,2 and 3 in One line in addition to already inlined item 1, in order to save some spaces in my answer sheet. [pls ignore my other iirelavant packages]

Comment: And which are irrelevant packages? You can omit them yourself :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Already found! just put another *:

```
\begin{enumerate*}
\item
\begin{enumerate*}
\item
\end{enumerate*}
\end{enumerate*}
```